# Possible to query the Case Origin set on an email-to-case?

Tags: soql, email2case

Is it possible to query the Case Origin that is set for each of the email-to-case?

I've used this query

> SELECT Id, IsActive, LocalPart, EmailDomainName, Function.FunctionName FROM EmailServicesAddress where Function.FunctionName='EmailToCase'

But doesn't give me the information I need. Ideally if I can see all the Origin set on the one page rather than going into each email-to-case to see the Origin that is set.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Maybe it is because I haven't interacted much with Email-to-Case, but I'm not really understanding what you are asking. I'm not following your last sentence at all.

Comment: What you want is to be able to query 'EmailToCaseRoutingAddress' to identify the origin. Sadly, this is not possible using SOQL. You can access it via the Metadata API I believe so you may be able to capture using Postman or something like that.

Comment: Hey Moonpie, When you set up an email-to-case you need to assign an 'Origin' when the case is created. So I was wondering if there is someway I can see a list of all the origins t hat is set for each of the email-to-case on one page rather than going to into each email-to-case to get that information.